# Dynamic controls in user control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm working on asp.net webform using VB language. In my webform I've created a user control which should list the data that it reads from the SQL Server database.

In the user control I want to create a script that reads from database and for each record it reads it should add control (like: `<li>, <span>, <div>,<h5>...`) dynamically out side the script but inside the user control page in order to be listed in the main/masterpage.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1nFq.png)

Comment: And what is the role of the PHP  tag here?

Comment: Where is PHP in your story :)

Comment: @Fafi Help you out with what? You haven't asked a question. Did you want someone to implement this for you? Then hire someone to do that. We're not here to just write your code for you, even if it is "urgent".

Comment: no I;m asking anyone to write a code, I just want to know which function that we can use that can create dynamically controls, and how to print it on the same  page

Comment: You can create controls and add them to the controls collection. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
yourPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<li>")) //opening tags
Label lbl = new Label()
lbl.Text = value_from_database;
yourPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</li>")) //closing tags
```

Hope it helps. Of course, if you mentioned this

Comment: thank you Mr. Khazratbek

Comment: Is it working as you need? @Fatiana

Comment: yes it is, thanks a lot

Comment: @Fafiana Glad to help you. Don't forget to approve the answer some day ))